# How to offset the scratch off effect when resizing window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In full screen, the scratch effect follows the cursor but resizing the image offsets the scratch-off effect from the pointer. How can I edit this so that when I resize it adjusts?

I know its something to do with the javascript, but I can't figure out exactly what I have to do to make this work. I tried following some of the steps within the javascript.

```js
(function() {

var image = { // back and front images
  'back': { 'url':'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2665/0346/files/fghjfghjfghjk.jpg?10582944971661792904', 'img':null },
 'front': { 'url':'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2665/0346/files/hjfghjgfhk.jpg?10582944971661792904', 'img':null }
};

var canvas = {'temp':null, 'draw':null}; // temp and draw canvases

var mouseDown = false;

/**
 * Helper function to get the local coords of an event in an element,
 * since offsetX/offsetY are apparently not entirely supported, but
 * offsetLeft/offsetTop/pageX/pageY are!
 *
 * @param elem element in question
 * @param ev the event
 */
function getLocalCoords(elem, ev) {
 var ox = 0, oy = 0;
 var first;
 var pageX, pageY;

 // Walk back up the tree to calculate the total page offset of the
 // currentTarget element.  I can't tell you how happy this makes me.
 // Really.
 while (elem != null) {
  ox += elem.offsetLeft;
  oy += elem.offsetTop;
  elem = elem.offsetParent;
 }

 if (ev.hasOwnProperty('changedTouches')) {
  first = ev.changedTouches[0];
  pageX = first.pageX;
  pageY = first.pageY;
 } else {
  pageX = ev.pageX;
  pageY = ev.pageY;
 }

 return { 'x': pageX - ox, 'y': pageY - oy };
}

/**
 * Recomposites the canvases onto the screen
 *
 * Note that my preferred method (putting the background down, then the
 * masked foreground) doesn't seem to work in FF with "source-out"
 * compositing mode (it just leaves the destination canvas blank.)  I
 * like this method because mentally it makes sense to have the
 * foreground drawn on top of the background.
 *
 * Instead, to get the same effect, we draw the whole foreground image,
 * and then mask the background (with "source-atop", which FF seems
 * happy with) and stamp that on top.  The final result is the same, but
 * it's a little bit weird since we're stamping the background on the
 * foreground.
 *
 * OPTIMIZATION: This naively redraws the entire canvas, which involves
 * four full-size image blits.  An optimization would be to track the
 * dirty rectangle in scratchLine(), and only redraw that portion (i.e.
 * in each drawImage() call, pass the dirty rectangle as well--check out
 * the drawImage() documentation for details.)  This would scale to
 * arbitrary-sized images, whereas in its current form, it will dog out
 * if the images are large.
 */
function recompositeCanvases() {
 var main = document.getElementById('maincanvas');
 var tempctx = canvas.temp.getContext('2d');
 var mainctx = main.getContext('2d');

 // Step 1: clear the temp
 canvas.temp.width = canvas.temp.width; // resizing clears

 // Step 2: stamp the draw on the temp (source-over)
 tempctx.drawImage(canvas.draw, 0, 0);

 /* !!!! this way doesn't work on FF:
  // Step 3: stamp the foreground on the temp (!! source-out mode !!)
  tempctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
  tempctx.drawImage(image.front.img, 0, 0);

  // Step 4: stamp the background on the display canvas (source-over)
  //mainctx.drawImage(image.back.img, 0, 0);

  // Step 5: stamp the temp on the display canvas (source-over)
  mainctx.drawImage(canvas.temp, 0, 0);
 */

 // Step 3: stamp the background on the temp (!! source-atop mode !!)
 tempctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
 tempctx.drawImage(image.back.img, 0, 0);

 // Step 4: stamp the foreground on the display canvas (source-over)
 mainctx.drawImage(image.front.img, 0, 0);

 // Step 5: stamp the temp on the display canvas (source-over)
 mainctx.drawImage(canvas.temp, 0, 0);
}

/**
 * Draw a scratch line
 * 
 * @param can the canvas
 * @param x,y the coordinates
 * @param fresh start a new line if true
 */
function scratchLine(can, x, y, fresh) {
 var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 ctx.lineWidth = 50;
 ctx.lineCap = ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00'; // can be any opaque color
 if (fresh) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  // this +0.01 hackishly causes Linux Chrome to draw a
  // "zero"-length line (a single point), otherwise it doesn't
  // draw when the mouse is clicked but not moved:
  ctx.moveTo(x+0.01, y);
 }
 ctx.lineTo(x, y);
 ctx.stroke();
}

/**
 * Set up the main canvas and listeners
 */
function setupCanvases() {
 var c = document.getElementById('maincanvas');
 // set the width and height of the main canvas from the first image
 // (assuming both images are the same dimensions)
 c.width = image.back.img.width;
 c.height = image.back.img.height;

 // create the temp and draw canvases, and set their dimensions
 // to the same as the main canvas:
 canvas.temp = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvas.draw = document.createElement('canvas');
 canvas.temp.width = canvas.draw.width = c.width;
 canvas.temp.height = canvas.draw.height = c.height;

 // draw the stuff to start
 recompositeCanvases();

 /**
  * On mouse down, draw a line starting fresh
  */
 function mousedown_handler(e) {
  var local = getLocalCoords(c, e);
  mouseDown = true;

  scratchLine(canvas.draw, local.x, local.y, true);
  recompositeCanvases();

  if (e.cancelable) { e.preventDefault(); } 
  return false;
 };

 /**
  * On mouse move, if mouse down, draw a line
  *
  * We do this on the window to smoothly handle mousing outside
  * the canvas
  */
 function mousemove_handler(e) {
  if (!mouseDown) { return true; }

  var local = getLocalCoords(c, e);

  scratchLine(canvas.draw, local.x, local.y, false);
  recompositeCanvases();

  if (e.cancelable) { e.preventDefault(); } 
  return false;
 };

 /**
  * On mouseup.  (Listens on window to catch out-of-canvas events.)
  */
 function mouseup_handler(e) {
  if (mouseDown) {
   mouseDown = false;
   if (e.cancelable) { e.preventDefault(); } 
   return false;
  }

  return true;
 };

 c.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown_handler, false);
 c.addEventListener('touchstart', mousedown_handler, false);

 window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove_handler, false);
 window.addEventListener('touchmove', mousemove_handler, false);

 window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup_handler, false);
 window.addEventListener('touchend', mouseup_handler, false);
}

/**
 * Set up the DOM when loading is complete
 */
function loadingComplete() {
 var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
 var main = document.getElementById('main');

 loading.className = 'hidden';
 main.className = '';
}

/**
 * Handle loading of needed image resources
 */
function loadImages() {
 var loadCount = 0;
 var loadTotal = 0;
 var loadingIndicator;

 function imageLoaded(e) {
  loadCount++;

  if (loadCount >= loadTotal) {
   setupCanvases();
   loadingComplete();
  }
 }

 for (k in image) if (image.hasOwnProperty(k))
  loadTotal++;

 for (k in image) if (image.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
  image[k].img = document.createElement('img'); // image is global
  image[k].img.addEventListener('load', imageLoaded, false);
  image[k].img.src = image[k].url;
 }
}

/**
 * Handle page load
 */
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 var resetButton = document.getElementById('resetbutton');

 loadImages();

 resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   // clear the draw canvas
   canvas.draw.width = canvas.draw.width;
   recompositeCanvases()

   return false;
  }, false);

}, false);

})();
```

```css
* {
  margin:0; padding:0;
}


#main { 
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:100%;
}

#maincanvas {
 border: 0px solid #222;
 cursor: pointer;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
        
<div><canvas id="maincanvas"></canvas></div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the resizing but the coordinates calculation. As you see here I naturally loaded the code (no resizing) and the drawing was already off.

[image]

Coordinates calculation for canvas is based on it's natural size, so if you resize the browser smaller or in my case already has a smaller browser than the canvas size the coordinates calculation will be off. You just have to correct your `x` and `y` to this. In `scratchLine()` before you use `x/y` correct it with something like this:

```
function coodinatesCorrection(x, y) {
  var c = document.getElementById('maincanvas');
  var naturalW = image.back.img.width;
  var naturalH = image.back.img.height;

  var w = c.offsetWidth;
  var h = c.offsetHeight;

  var correctX = (x / w) * naturalW;
  var correctY = (y / h) * naturalH;

  return [correctX, correctY];
}
```

Here it is in action: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRygBO?editors=0010